# What do, the two options `using explicit_module groups` and using `qualified names` do?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

What do, the two options `using explicit_module groups` and using `qualified names` do?I am using IntelliJ IDEA community version.Why is the Gradle New Project creation process step 3 window of IntelliJ IDEA Community version different from the step 3 window of the IntelliJ IDEA video at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html?.The step 3 window in the video does not have the two options.